# Optimal Database

Tags: database, optimization, rethinkdb, rules

In the design of the database tables, is it better to have a field with our own rules, or some fields, each of which represents a particular thing ?

for example :

In the blog table, we have a field named (Status) that accepts those integer numbers, and we set our rules for this field,

If it was 1, it means being inactive

If there was 2, it meant the image

If there was 3, it meant the presence of the video

I want these personal and private rules, for example

---

Or it can be a field as (isActive), meaning it is inactive

And a field means an image (isImage -> bool)

And a field means a video (IsVideo -> bool)

Comment: What if it's inactive AND has video?

Comment: This is just an example of the story

Comment: And mine was the answer. There's no one "universally optimal" way. It all depends on your requirements.